# Why I used multithreading to remove object from NSUserDefault, it still cause the animation frames dropped

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove some object from my NSUserDefault when I pop up the current viewController, but if I remove them directly it will cause the pop up animation frames dropped. So I used multithreading which it still didn't work.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("remove_object", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"selectNameArr"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"selectPhonetArr"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"add_member_name_arr"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"add_member_phone_arr"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"sesion"];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"row"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    });

}
```

Comment: This method is called when the view is already disappeared, not during the transition. Check if you're doing something during the transition and check if your view has a background color (not clear). Sometimes it makes the transition noisy.

Comment: @Otto Ying, there can be other reasons for animation drop. No need to put NSUserDefaults in background thread. Does your app uploading or downloading any content?

Comment: @HirenPatel Nope. Just when I pop up the current view and no any other networking in background. My friend told me using the `setObect:nil forKey:@"xxx"` instead of `removeObjectForKey ` and it work for me. So now I just wonder is there any solution I can address the `removeObjectForKey ` problem.

Comment: From class NSUserDefaults, 

/// -removeObjectForKey: is equivalent to -[... setObject:nil forKey:defaultName]
- (void)removeObjectForKey:(NSString *)defaultName;

Comment: @HirenPatel Yeah, I aware of that. It's the most creepy thing